# Migrating to discord.py 2.0 put asyncpg isn't working

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, discord.py, asyncpg

I have an old bot that I'm trying to transfer to discord.py v2. Asyncpg isn't working and I'm not sure why. I've tried putting the `loop` and `pool` in the on_ready and setup_hook but that didn't work either.

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import asyncpg


# Pydest

# Define Client
class Aclient(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents.default())
        self.synced = False


    async def setup_hook(self):

        cog = await self.load_extension('cogs.weather')
        print(f"Loaded All Cogs")
        if not self.synced:
            await self.tree.sync()
            self.synced = True
    

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()

        if not self.synced:
            await self.tree.sync()
            self.synced = True

        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd)
        print(f'We have logged in as {self.user}')


client=Aclient()

# test command
@client.tree.command(name="test", description="testing")
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction, name: str):
    async with pool.acquire() as connection:
        async with connection.transaction():
            check = await connection.fetchrow('select * from weather')
            print(check)
    await connection.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
pool = loop.run_until_complete(asyncpg.create_pool(**credentials))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/prathik/Documents/GitHub/red/YELLOW/bot.py", line 61, in test
    async with connection.transaction():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/transaction.py", line 62, in __aenter__
    await self.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/transaction.py", line 138, in start
    await self._connection.execute(query)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 317, in execute
    return await self._protocol.query(query, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 338, in query
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='CommandTree-invoker' coro=<CommandTree._from_interaction.<locals>.wrapper() running at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py:1089>> got Future <Future pending cb=[Protocol._on_waiter_completed()]> attached to a different loop

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 851, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/prathik/Documents/GitHub/red/YELLOW/bot.py", line 60, in test
    async with pool.acquire() as connection:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 220, in release
    raise ex
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 210, in release
    await self._con.reset(timeout=budget)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1366, in reset
    await self.execute(reset_query, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 317, in execute
    return await self._protocol.query(query, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 323, in query
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 707, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol._check_state
asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1240, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 876, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 869, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'test' raised an exception: InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Store a pool attribute in your it instead of a global variable with ``run_until_complete``. Also don't auto-sync.

Comment: @stijndcl wait sorry, store the pool attribute where?

Comment: In your **bot**. Auto-correct must've messed up my previous comment, not sure what happened there. Just create an attr in your bot subclass & create the pool once on startup (in `setup_hook`)